# visual-studio-cordova install android sdk blocks

Tags: installation, visual-studio-cordova

Hi I am trying to install Tools for Apache Cordova For Visual Studio 2013 - CTP3.1  I have Visual Studio 2013 Premium with Update 4 installed.
The Installer gets stuck when Android SDK being installed. I have cancelled the installer and tried again but same issue reoccurs. I have tried leaving the installer for 24 hours...no luck - darn

I did a clean reboot (kb:929135) and that didn't help.

Log files can be found here: http://1drv.ms/1LwmJhv

screenshot of installer progress : http://1drv.ms/1Gs7qQ6

Does anyone have any suggestions?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

While we look at the logs, you can install the dependencies (specifically Android SDK) manually. Please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054.aspx#ThirdParty on how to install these dependencies manually.

Answer (score 0):

when I install sdk in Hong Kong, it was successful, then I bring the same laptop to China and install it again, it fails.  At last I found that the China government blocks access to *.google.com    Then in China, I need to establish a Vpn connection to Hong Kong then install the sdk, it works!

Is your country block access to google as well?

Comment: this is something not related at all